# Saving DStream on HDFS custom location

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

Spark DStream has method saveAsTextFiles(prefix, [suffix]) which can be used to save data on HDFS but this function does not accept any path parameter.

```
myDStream.saveAsTextFiles("prefix_","_suffix")
```

By default , it is saving data into current logged in user directory on HDFS i.e. if you are running application with root user then data is stored in

```
/user/root/prefix_TIMESTAMP_suffx
```

How do I change output directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a path to the desired HDFS directory as the prefix argument:

```
myDStream.saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://my/custom/path/prefix_","_suffix")
```